# struct embeding, function inputs, polymorphism

Tags: function, go, input, struct, types

I have a parent struct :

```
type BigPoly struct{
    Value []*ring.Poly
}
```

And two child structs :

```
type Plaintext BigPoly
type Ciphertext BigPoly
```

I would like to have functions accepting both Plaintext and Ciphertext. My solution is to use a function of the form :

```
func Add(a *Ciphertext, b interface{}) (*Ciphertext)
```

and use a switch-case to decide what to do, but I find it troublesome and it can lead to very complicated cases if the number of inputs grows.

However since Plaintext and Ciphertext have exactly the same structure and internal variables and only differ in their name, is it possible to create a function accepting both Plaintext and Ciphertext in a cleaner way ? I.e. it doesn't care if it is a type Plaintext or Ciphertext, as long as it is a type BigPoly.

Comment: There are no "child" or "parent" structs in Go. What you have are distinct types, with no parent/child relationships.

Comment: The proper approach to your problem is to use an interface (not an empty one). Perhaps `interface Poly { Value() []*ring.Poly }`. Then have your function accept that interface.

Answer (score 0):

Use a non-empty interface:

```
type Poly interface {
    Value() []*ring.Poly
}
```

Then define your struct as:

```
type BigPoly struct{
    value []*ring.Poly
}

func (p *BigPoly) Value() []*ring.Poly {
    return p.value
}
```

And your consumer as:

```
func Add(a, b Poly) Poly {
    aValue := a.Value()
    bValue := b.Value()
    // ... do something with aValue and bValue
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But where do the Ciphertext and Plaintext type fit in? I would still like to be able to differentiate between them.

Comment: You can still use them. Just make sure they satisfy the interface.

Comment: Yes right, my bad, it works well, thank you very much.